# Syncronize merge on multiple git projects

Tags: git

I have a big project `Main` containing multiple subprojects, let's say `A` and `B`. Each subproject is an independant git repo I have control over, and each subproject can be branched and merged individually during development.

What I need now is a way to create syncronized branches between mutliple subprojects. For instance, I want to add the file `test.txt` inside A and B. I want to create a branch at the Main project level, and I need to be sure that the merge of that work into master in my Main project will result into the merge of the work into each subproject, at the same time, in order to guarantee consistency between my subprojects.

Let's discuss a more concrete example. Imagine I have a `Website`project with a subproject `Backend` and a subproject `frontend`. I would like to be able to add a feature that will change the back and the front by just merging a single branch of the Website project.

What are the best ways to achieve that ? From what I read so far, submodules doesn't seem to be fitted for that task.

**Edit 0** Of course, I could just commit and push the changes in each subproject, but actually, quite often our small team can happen to make changes impacting up to 4 different projects, so it is time consuming to create branches and merges in all 4 subprojects. Moreover, in our process, the changes will be reviewed by someone else before the merge, so chances are high that the merge will not be syncronized, leading potentially to unstable behaviour

**Edit 1** I found [this about sub-repos](https://github.com/ingydotnet/git-subrepo#readme). Would you think that this would be the correct way to go?

**Edit 2** I will try to be more precise. Submodule, composite, yarn or npm all allow me to import remote projects as dependencies and pull the update from there. My real issue is how to push back changes made in each submodule to their respective remote repo. I found `git subtree` and `git subrepo` that both seem to achieve that, but I didn't get the expected result so far. Which one of these solutions should I focus on?

Comment: For me it doesn't look like a typical git problem. Maybe you think about to create a `Platform` project where you maintain all the stuff that belongs to project A and B. This platform project is later easy to integrate via a subtree. From there on you only make changes in the `Platform` and automatically share it.

Comment: Is it an option just to merge all repos into one? That might make life easier...

Comment: It seems you have a misconception in your environment. IMO a sub-repo mustn't share any files with another sub-repo. This must lead to collisions otherwise. But if you do have the same files checked in into your sub-repos you have to decide the merge. You may show an example of your file- / git-locations so one can say where the cruelpit is.

Comment: `sub-repo mustn't share any files with another sub-repo`I agree with that, I'm not saying that files are shared, but rather that sometimes, changes made to one subproject will make sense only if syncronized with some changes made in another subproject

Comment: `This platform project is later easy to integrate via a subtree`Oh, yeah, I didn't know about subtree. It seems to be the way to go, don't you think?

Comment: So think about a third repo C with the common shared files. So A & B requires C. And while talking about front- & backend: If you use PHP, take a look at [composer](http://getcomposer.org). Makes it a lot easier to update your dependencies, if you change C.

Comment: I have 3 backend subprojects, and 3 frontend projects, and 2 modules that are dependencies of multiple subprojects. It is all written in node + React. Npm makes it quite easy to update dependencies, but it is not really the matter here.

Comment: `Is it an option just to merge all repos into one? ` No. The projects need to remain independant.

Comment: Using [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules), you could specify in your `Main` repo which version (read: which commit) of the submodules to include. That way, you could perform some changes on `A` and on `B` and when you have both the way you want them to, you can locally checkout the versions of `A` and `B` that you want and add them both to your `Main` repo. Then commit that.

Is this what you want or do the changes have to change the files in the submodules?

Comment: @Sharcoux `git submodules` was meant to do what NPM does now in a much better way (imo). You have the choice, but I recommend to using a repo as a library and updating it via NPM.

Comment: @lucidbrot You're getting to it. The issue with submodule is that it works only one way, whereas I need to be able to push from a master branch to each subprojects where changes occured

Comment: @Sharcoux Ah, so you have some changes which must happen simultaneously, one change in `A` and one in `B`. Would it not be sufficient to perform the changes locally in `A` and `B`, commit them and then push both almost at the same time?

Comment: Yeah, that would work of course, but actually, quite often our small team can happen to make changes impacting up to 4 different projects, so it is time consuming to create branches and merges in all 4 subprojects. Moreover, in our process, the changes will be reviewed by someone else before the merge, so chances are high that the merge will not be syncronized, leading potentially to unstable behaviour